# When I edit a point, press save, it says saved, but really doesn't

Tags: qgis, point, editing

I'm a newbie in GIS.
The problems starts when I import some points gather from QField.
I was improving my fields while learning, to have drop down options in some features, but now I can't save my edits.
I've copied a layer from QField to my project and now both, the new and the old data cannot be saved, you can edit, says Changes saved but really don't.

i.e.
[image: how looks the feature attribute table]
[image: Feature Attribute for the above point]

[image: Selecting two fields to be true]

[image: results]

[image: nothing happends]
[image: Attribute form]
[image: Old data with T and F instead of true or false]
then save, but when you click again in that point with **Identify Features button**, nothing changed.
Any tips?

Steps:

1. click one point to see the values(img1).
2. right click on data and **Edit Feature Form..**
3. Modify any feature, in this case, **Nap de otra operadora** and **Cruceta**, press **OK**
4. Save layer.
5. Click again on the same point and results in no changes in features.

Comment: Sorry, but seems like I dont understand your issue. As I see it, your first screenshot is your starting point and the second one represents its settings. The third one are then your settings and your last one shows these settings. Seems correct. Can you clarify?

Comment: as you can see, the fourth one is how the features changes after i click in OK, then i press save, click again on the point and the result is the fifth one, where nothing changed.

Comment: What setting did you use when you set the form ? could you show your form setting for tone of the field that didn't work ?

Comment: Is yor data in gpx format? That would explain the behavior as you can' t edit gpx files in QGIS. In this case, export as Geopackage or Shapefile and try editing there.

Comment: See creation issues of the GDAL library used in QGIS regarding gpx: "Update of existing files is not currently supported."https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpx.html

Comment: @J.R how can I show that? I'll add it to my post, explain it please. because i didn't know how to add a layer before, i just open my qfiel project from my phone, then copied the layer, closed the qfield project, open my main project, add that layer to that, copied new points and add to Postes layer, maybe then i started with errors.  <br/>

Comment: @babel i think my data is in shp and geopackage format.

Comment: Right click on your layer and select "Properties..." then go to the "Attribute form Tab" and select one of the field that didn't save. Now review the widget type for the field (it seem you are using checkbox so check that the representation for checked and unchecked state are correctly defined)

Comment: @J.R uploaded attribute form, before, it was **'T'** and **'F'** as true or false in checkbox, but now in the box says(or i changed) **true** and **false** for states of checked or unchecked and default also **false**.  <br/>Also, the new ones are in true or false form, and the old data stays in T and F as you can see in the last image.